# How to enable javascript into webView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

In android if I use javascript into webView it gives Force Close. Is there any possibilities for using java script into webView. please help...

```
01-10 10:08:51.513: W/dalvikvm(5994): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x407447a8 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
01-10 10:08:51.513: I/dalvikvm(5994): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
01-10 10:08:51.513: I/dalvikvm(5994):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40567400 self=0x1f9e58
01-10 10:08:51.513: I/dalvikvm(5994):   | sysTid=6010 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2269896
01-10 10:08:51.513: I/dalvikvm(5994):   | schedstat=( 44479977019 41285891893 14352 )
01-10 10:08:51.513: I/dalvikvm(5994):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
01-10 10:08:51.513: I/dalvikvm(5994):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
01-10 10:08:51.543: I/dalvikvm(5994):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:53)
01-10 10:08:51.543: I/dalvikvm(5994):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1158)
01-10 10:08:51.543: I/dalvikvm(5994):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 10:08:51.543: I/dalvikvm(5994):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-10 10:08:51.543: I/dalvikvm(5994):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
01-10 10:08:51.557: I/dalvikvm(5994):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-10 10:08:51.557: E/dalvikvm(5994): VM aborting
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

JavaScript is disabled in a WebView by default.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 13):

Enabling JS in WebView in **Kotlin**:

```
val webView = web_view_id
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 9):

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In some versions you may have to do it like this:

```
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To enabled JavaScript create you need to create a `configuration` parameter for `WebView` init

```
struct VideoView: View, UIViewRepresentable {
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
            let configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            let preferences: WKWebpagePreferences = WKWebpagePreferences()
            preferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
            configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences = preferences
            let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView(
                frame: .zero,
                configuration: configuration
            )
            return webView
        }
        
        func updateUIView(_ UIView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
            guard let url = URL("") else {return}
            UIView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
            UIView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
```