# How to put the textpadding in webview in android?

Tags: android, html, webview, padding

i have one html file.And i display this html file using webview.
i try to display the all text contain page wise.so i lock the scrolling of webview.
And display page wise.
My problem is when i display some text contain according to webview height some last part of text is cut and display half.

**like this**

[image: Display text cut image.]

**so my problem is how to put the text padding in webview like a textview?**

- EDIT

**CODE**

```
wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        //This is gesture For webpage
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(myContext, new MyGestureDetector());//This For swipe gesture.
        wv.setOnTouchListener(this);
        wv.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);//Stop Horizontal scroll.
```

**Load Webview Url Data.**

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", All_Xml_str,"text/html" , "utf-8", "");
```

**All_Xml_Str. get the whole contain of html.**

i am stuck.
i try so many thing but can't success.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: try to format your html file and check in webview

Comment: @Ramkiran i try all of the possible thing.it's page of one epub file and i read this and display like this.but can't success.

Comment: once check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9170954/1265724)

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh paste your code here.

Comment: @Ramkiran i already try this link

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh add this line wv.setInitialScale(90); in your code and check it

Comment: @ChiragPatel i use this but same result.

Comment: If you have `string` parsed then why you are loading it in webview, why don't you show in a `textview` itself with `Html.loadHtml(string);`

Comment: @MKJParekh it's epub file page it's contain vedio,image audio so in textview this can't work so i use webview

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to format the data separately in JavaScript. Tag and class all the elements in the script and then throw in some CSS to pretty things up using those classes. To save processing time for multiple views, I would cache the processed blob in a database.

Remember to [**enable Javascript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846077/how-to-enable-java-script-into-webview) in your webview settings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try set domStorageEnabled in settings webview?

example: webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true